# Batch Windows - How to create a loop to rename many files in different folders?

Tags: batch-rename

I have PDF files in one location (all in the same folder), which I need to take 3 useful information from the file name.

And I have .jpg files in another location (1 picture per folder) which I need to rename with these information taken from the PDF.

My script is able to find the information, store and rename but it only works for the first file in a directory and then stops.
I need to make it run in a loop until there is either no more PDF files to take information from OR no more .jpg files to be renamed.

Can someone help me to make this script run in a loop?

```
echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem User input
SET /P datework= Please type the date you want to work (format yyyymmdd):

rem Folder where the PDFs are located - extract the useful information from file name
cd /D C:\Users\A\Desktop\A_tests\QC\PDF\%datework%\

for %%i in (*.pdf) do (
    set RcvLn=%%i
    set RcvLn=!RcvLn:~0,4!
    set GunStn=%%i
    set GunStn=!GunStn:~5,4!
    set Node=%%i
    set Node=!Node:~10,4!
)

rem Rename the pictures using the values stored on the variables
xcopy /Y "C:\Users\A\Desktop\A_tests\QC\UHD73\Node Deployment\%datework%\Node %Node%\*.jpg" "C:\Users\A\Desktop\A_tests\QC\UHD73\Node Deployment\%datework%\Node%Node%_RL%RcvLn%_GS%GunStn%.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set each variable inside of the loop for each file, but then you do the xcopy outside of the loop which will only do the xcopy once. So we rather do the xcopy inside the loop.

```
echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem User input
SET /P datework= Please type the date you want to work (format yyyymmdd):

rem Folder where the PDFs are located - extract the useful information from file name
cd /D C:\Users\A\Desktop\A_tests\QC\PDF\%datework%

for %%i in (*.pdf) do (
    set RcvLn=%%i
    set RcvLn=!RcvLn:~0,4!
    set GunStn=%%i
    set GunStn=!GunStn:~5,4!
    set Node=%%i
    set Node=!Node:~10,4!
    echo xcopy /Y "C:\Users\A\Desktop\A_tests\QC\UHD73\Node Deployment\!datework!\Node !Node!\*.jpg" "C:\Users\A\Desktop\A_tests\QC\UHD73\Node Deployment\!datework!\Node!Node!_RL!RcvLn!_GS!GunStn!.jpg"
)
```

Comment: Thank you Gerhard! Such an easy solution.. I think it was too late last night for me to see it. :P :)